# How to find out the name of repository in order to specify with `apt-get install -t`?

Tags: debian, apt

I know I could use the following commands for choosing an repository:

```
apt-get install -t backports|testing|unstable|etc software
```

I recently had to work with the mysql-repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-5.7
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-tools
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-5.7
```

How could I find out the name of that repository to specify it with the `-t` option?

```
apt-get install -t mysql-community mysql-server
E: The value 'mysql-community' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
apt-get install -t mysql-5.7 mysql-server
E: The value 'mysql-5.7' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
apt-get install -t mysql mysql-server
E: The value 'mysql' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

I didn't find any information about that in `apt-cache showpkg mysql-server`, too. Also, is there some sort of command which will list all repositories on my system?

Comment: Is it `stretch` (I am no expert on this), but maybe it gets mixed in.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? As in, doesn’t `apt install mysql-server` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The `-t` option doesn’t specify a repository, it specifies a release (it’s short-hand for the `APT::Default-Release` setting; see `man apt_preferences`).

You can see what release a given repository targets by looking at its `Release` file, [here in your case](http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/stretch/Release). That specifies `stretch` (look for `Codename:`), so you’re not going to be able to use that...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to obtain information about your repositories, execute:

```
sudo apt-cache policy
```

But this can't help you to achieve your goal. If you want to install a package from some specific repository, you have select not a repository, but specific package version. To have list of all versions for the `mysql-server` package, do:

```
apt-show-versions | grep mysql-server
```

In my Ubuntu 18.04 the output is

```
mysql-server:all/bionic-security 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 uptodate
mysql-server-5.7:amd64/bionic-security 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 uptodate
mysql-server-5.7:i386 not installed
mysql-server-core-5.7:amd64/bionic-security 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 uptodate
mysql-server-core-5.7:i386 not installed
```

If you wish to specify a repository, just grep it from `apt search`, for example, for `bionic-updates` repository execute:

```
apt search linux-image | grep -i bionic-updates
```

Afterwards select version you need and install it, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7:amd64
```

Thus, the rule for you is: **select version of package instead of repository.**

If you need older version of package to avoid its upgrade use `apt-mark`:

```
sudo apt-mark hold mysql-server-5.7
```

The last command prevents package upgrading. Use unhold to revert this behavior:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold mysql-server-5.7
```

Additionally see my answer for similar question at Askubuntu: [Ubuntu 16.04 and kernel 4.15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054742/ubuntu-16-04-and-kernel-4-15/1054746#1054746)

Another option for you can be **[pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)**, read carefully this topic: [How to only install updates from a specific repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository)

Comment: On Debian testing (bookworm), as of this comment, I had to use (for *nodejs*, considering Debian borked the package (it's currently `16.13.2+really14.19.1~dfsg-6` in Debian's repository, and `14.19.1-deb-1nodesource1` on nodesource, so you can imagine which one is taking priority), I had to first `sudo apt-get install nodejs=14.19.1-deb-1nodesource1`, and then I could `sudo apt-mark hold nodejs=14.19.1-deb-1nodesource1`. Any other formatting of the commands failed.